# Multiple of 9 function

Tags: r

I want to write a function in R which accepts a list of integers and returns only the values in the original list that are divisible by 9.

This is what I have done so far:

```
multipleof9=function(x){
return(((x %% 9 == 0) 
}
```

but this only works for one value of `x`, not a list of integers

Comment: you need to put your code here, we dont do everything for you. nine nine nine gooold ♪♫♪♫

Comment: Why so many negatives ?? i thought this was a fair enough thing to do to practise my skills on R :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
multipleof9 <- function(x) {
    return(x[x %% 9 == 0])
  }
```

You just need to subset `x` with the logical vector returned by `x %% 9 == 0`

Note that the use of `return` is completely optional. That is,

```
multipleOf9 <- function(x) x[x %% 9 == 0]
```

is equivalent.

Comment: I dont understand.  What do you mean subset x with the logical vector

Comment: Hey Buckminster, is there a way of doing this so that the argument of the function can be a list of integers.  In other words, make the function accept a list of integers and return only those divisible by 9